# Open-shift-Running Handler [openshift_master : verify API Server] FAILED - RETRYING Verify API Server

Tags: openshift, redhat, openshift-enterprise, openshift-3

I am Trying to Install Openshift 3.9.1 In CentOS 7.5. All the process Done but Below Failed Issue Occurring. If you have any suggestion about it,

( Running Handler [ openshift_master : verify API Server ])
FAILED - RETRYING Verify API Server (120 retries left).

install configuration

[image]

problem occurring...

[image]

If any proper step by step guideline notice me. thanks

Comment: When you say "proper step by step guideline", are you saying you haven't even read https://docs.openshift.org/3.9/install_config/install/advanced_install.html It would cover pre-requisites for installation etc.

Comment: I was follwing official tutorial.. https://blog.openshift.com/installing-openshift-3-7-1-30-minutes/

Comment: This is usually problem of network configuration. Do you see something in the system logs?

Comment: I like to configure it without any public domain. I like to access openshift server interface in my localhost or local pc Ip. I like to create a private cloud server on my machine.